# Combine the data from multiple excel files by transposing the data in individual sheets of all files

Tags: powerquery

Please help me out to my problem.

I needs to combine the multipule excel files with different files names by transposing the data of each file. All the files are having same and unique data in first column. The first column of individual files are needs to be in header.

While trying to combine & transpose the data, the fist column of individual files are getting transpose with multiple times as the count of files including the source file name which need not to transpose.

Answer (score 0):

This will combine every tab from each XLSX file in a directory, doing a full transpose on each individual table before combining them

```
let Source = Folder.Files("C:\subdirectory\directory"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Name", "Content"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "GetFileData", each Excel.Workbook([Content],true)),
#"Expanded GetFileData" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "GetFileData", {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Name"}, {"Data", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind", "Sheet"}),
#"Transpose"=Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded GetFileData","Data2", each  Table.PromoteHeaders(Table.Transpose(Table.DemoteHeaders([Data]))) ),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Transpose",{"Content", "Hidden", "Item", "Kind","Data"}),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Removed Columns"[Data2], each Table.ColumnNames(_))),
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data2", List,List)
in  #"Expanded Data"
```